# triggering a event in background by using alarm manager

Tags: android

I am trying out with an android app . In which i have to do something at particular time (say 8am) daily  . Now my app must run in background because user will not keep the app in foreground all the time .

So basically once my app is installed for first time it asks for the timings the phone will be turned to silent . And then it should run as a service . So daily in the specified timing the phone should go silent.

I thought of making app as a binding service . ie once the user gives the timing the service will be started . But once the user closes the foreground app(which i used to get timings)  , the service will also be terminated ?

If yes now how should i proceed . i searched a lot but got more confused .

Comment: YOu don't want it as a bound service.  Do it as a service started by startService.  Then it doesn't need a bound activity.

Comment: @GabeSechan Okie if i am starting it as a service , if the user closes the UI activity (which i use to get input ) , does the service also gets closed . And how should i make the service to turn off sound at specified timing . I thought of using Alarm Manager .But how should i do . Help me .

Comment: Services stick around even if there is no activity, as long as the device doesn't run out of memory and close it for that reason.  And yes, use AlarmManager to do something at a given time.